# Android -  Basic Authenticated HTTP Request

Tags: android

So basically i need my android app to connect to a web service using a url as such
"http://username:password@0.0.0.0" aka basic authentication.
obviously the username and password are checked by the web app before allowing access and otherwise doesn't allow the request.

my issue is that all the methods i try always say unauthorised (response code 401) regardless of what combination of classes and methods ive used to try and connect to the the url.

The web app in question is designed to return things only is un/pw clears otherwise it returns nothing, the web app and un/pw etc have all be checked and cleared.

so does anyone no the correct way to send a request to a url like that and have it work correctly?

android api8 btw

**UPDATE**
Turns out my issue is due to the web app using NTLM windows authentication which is not supported directly by androids/apache http library, investigating appropriate workarounds now

Comment: What have you tried exactly? The web is most probably using Basic or Digest authentication, 
all you have to do is create the appropriate headers and add them to your request. HttpClient even has APIs to this for you.

Comment: various implementations of adding headers or authentication info to the request such as the ones in HTTPClient and the likes of whats been posted below

Comment: This still means nothing without the actual details. The bigger question is though: are you 100% your server is using Basic auth? It could be digest authentication or some custom scheme. Get wire dumps, server logs, etc.

Comment: im about 99% sure yes, i am in the process of getting logs etc now

Answer (score 8):

Here's some code form a really old project of mine.  I used basic auth for some web service, and this worked at the time.  I'm not sure if there are updated api's since then (this was Android 1.6), but it should still work.

```
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI(url));

            UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials =
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(authUser, authPass);
            BasicScheme scheme = new BasicScheme();
            Header authorizationHeader = scheme.authenticate(credentials, request);
            request.addHeader(authorizationHeader);
```

Basically, Basic HTTP auth is a simple hash of the user and password.  The browser allows you to stuff these values in the url, but it actually does the work of adding the basic auth header to your request.

Comment: you combine the 2 first lines into one for newer api versions like so
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

unfortunately this hasn't solved my issue, im beginning to think its an issue with the actual web app side of it :s