# HTTP Get Android with Basic Auth

Tags: android, basic-authentication

I'm new to REST services and I'm looking for a few hours around the web...

I have a REST service url that gives me back **JSON data**.
The login (username & password) are **basic auth**.
I'm looking for a simple **library/code snippet** that lets me insert the uri, username & password and give me back the JSON string.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android -  Basic Authenticated HTTP Request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920559/android-basic-authenticated-http-request)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("YOUR WEBSITE HERE");

// Add authorization header
httpGet.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate( new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "password"), "UTF-8", false));

// Set up the header types needed to properly transfer JSON
httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
try {
      HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
      StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
      int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
      if (statusCode == 200) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          builder.append(line);
        }
      } else {
        Log.e(ParseJSON.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
      }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As for writing a JSONObject, check out this code snippet:

```
public void writeJSON() {
  JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
  try {
    object.put("name", "Jack Hack");
    object.put("score", new Integer(200));
    object.put("current", new Double(152.32));
    object.put("nickname", "Hacker");
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  System.out.println(object);
}
```

Comment: This gives me " error: cannot find symbol method setEntity(UrlEncodedFormEntity)"

Comment: Oops. Forgot that you're not allowed to add those things in Http GET requests - only POST. See my updated answer. @TomCB

Comment: I get statuscode 401, I guess that means some problem with authorisation

Comment: @TomCB You are correct, 401 typically means you have invalid credentials. But you were able to use the android code to execute the HTTP GET request right? If this answered your question, please vote up and indicate it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following library...

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ (No Affiliation)

This allows you to use the following syntax to set the basic authentication and fire a GET request to the server...

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.setBasicAuth("username", "password");
client.get("http://myurl.com", null, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes) {
                String json = new String(bytes); // This is the json.
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes, Throwable throwable) {

            }
        });
```

It's dead easy and the library has alot of main stream support from some of the large applications on Google Play such as Pintrest / Instagram etc!

Comment: This gives me the error that onSucces & onFailure: "Method does not override method from it's superclass"

Comment: You have copied and pasted the code exactly? I have literally just pasted this from a working example.

Comment: Just take a look at the website I linked.. there are plenty of examples.

Comment: 4 years later, I will try it

Answer (score 1):

Note to @erad's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26176707/1386969)

The method **BasicScheme.authenticate** is deprecated.

Instead of using this:

```
httpGet.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate( new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "password"), "UTF-8", false));
```

you should use this:

```
    String userName = "bla bla";
    String password = "top secret";
    UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName, password);
    Header basicAuthHeader = new BasicScheme(Charset.forName("UTF-8")).authenticate(credentials, httpGet, null);
    httpGet.addHeader(basicAuthHeader);
```