# Kotlin: how to perform a HTTP post request for login authentication

Tags: android, android-studio, http, kotlin

I am trying to set up a login page for my android studio app, using Kotlin, but I need to send the login details to my url.

How can I use a HTTP post request to send a username and password to a given url?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26176707/10934959

Comment: Actually the answer to this depends on the server implementation. Ask your backend dev for Login API.

Answer (score 0):

that's simple and you can do it in many ways,
One of the simple way is use this library:
https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking see Making a POST Request

or use Retrofit

Comment: Thank you! One more question, is there any major disadvantages of using such libraries?

Comment: libraries like these are trend,use it ,Use these, they have no particular harm